# May I speak of the effect of two Xs "on together"?

Tags: word-usage

Do I use "Effect" and "on together" appropriately in my sentence?

> I want to analyse the effects of two consecutive irrigation gate on
>   together.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean "together" as in "at the same time"?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the effect of one irrigation gate on another irrigation gate, then you'd better use **each other** instead of **together**, so it becomes:

> I want to analyse the effects of two consecutive irrigation gates on
>   **each other**.

Otherwise if you mean **together** as **at the same time** as user  Catija said in the comment, then the sentence below is fine:

> I want to analyse the effects of having two consecutive irrigation gates together.

Besides that, you should use gate in plural form: **gates**

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to put it:

- I want to analyse the **combined effect** of two consecutive irrigation gates.